# Display values of multiple checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, input, accordion

I need help with jQuery.

I have an easyui accordion with text and checkboxes, and in each accordion I have multiple inputs. The value of inputs is read form php arrays.

I want do display the value of each input when checked (unchecked hide the value).

And display all the values in span with current class .values separated by comma. And I have problem with this because I don't know how to display all the values ..

I have tried this

```
 $('#sub_number').on('change', function () {
     var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
     $('.values').html(val);
 });
```

But it didn't work, and I don't know should I use the input id, or parent div id or just input selector in jQuery. Should you help me with this code ?

My code below

```
<span class="values"></span>
<div id='easyui-tabs'>
    <div id="tab9081">
        <div class="group easyui-accordion">
            <div class="subgroup" title="1">
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="1.a"/><label>1233</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="1.b"/><label>3444</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="1.c"/><label>eee</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="1.e"/><label>dede</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="1.f"/><label>eded</label></p>
            </div>
            <div class="subgroup" title="2">
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="2.a"/><label>eded</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="2.b"/><label>deded</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="2.c"/><label>dede</label></p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="sub_number" value="2.d"/><label>frf</label></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
 var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
 $(this).parent().html(val);
});
```

Check our the working of my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFn2M/

Your example has a lot elements with the same id (sub_number). An id needs to be unique over the whole document. If this is not the case use classes instead.